# help on mysql query JOIN, ORDER BY and randomize

Tags: mysql

i am joining 2 tables using this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (member.id), member_type FROM member 
LEFT JOIN member_gallery 
ON member.id = member_gallery.member_id 
WHERE member.front = 1 
ORDER BY member.member_type ASC
```

suppose that i have 4 member types

- 20 members for type no.1
- 20 members for type no.2
- 20 members for type no.3
- 20 members for type no.4

and i am displaying this on my web as a 6x5 image grid, is it possible for me to randomize the fetch data, while maintaining the ORDER BY member.member_type ASC, like using ORDER BY RAND() ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ORDER BY member.member_type ASC, RAND()
```